# ExoPlayer shuffle doesn't reproduce all the songs

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am creating a music player using exoplayer library. Everything works fine except the shuffle that is no behaving as I expect.

The problem that I have is the following:

Imagine that I have 5 songs:

song 1

song 2

song 3

song 4

song 5

and I am in the first one. Then I click on shuffle button and enable shuffled using `exoPlayer.shuffleModeEnabled = true`. Then now the order is the following:

song 4

song 2

song 5

song 1

song 3

As I was in song 1, after that it will go to song 3 and then it will finish without reproducing song 4, 2 and 5. The behavior that I spec is to reproduce all the songs in a random order. Is there any way to achieve that with exoplayer?

Comment: have you find any solution or another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own ShuffleOrder to achieve this. One way to do this is to extend the [DefaultShuffleOrder](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/ShuffleOrder.java#L32) class and use a member field to store the starting index (in your example, it should be song 1). You should override the following methods:

```
getNextIndex(int index)
getPreviousIndex(int index)
getFirstIndex()
getLastIndex()
```

The idea is to make it a circular list. In your example, assume the shuffle order is 4, 2, 5, 1, 3 and 1 is currently being played, your `getFirstIndex()` should return 1, and `getLastIndex()` should return 5. For `getNextIndex(int index)` and `getPreviousIndex(int index)`, do what it's supposed to do, but when you reach the head/tail just loop it around.

Then, when you want to activate shuffling, you do:

```
concatenatingMediaSource.setShuffleOrder(new MyShuffleOrder());
```